# IOS11 Beta ARKit can't scale Scene object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I created a basic scene, and added an dae file. 
First every time i run or save the project i get the popup: 
The document “billboard.dae” could not be saved.

It still runs though but is annoying.

But the issue is I can't scale the object.
I have tried different values 0.5s and also > 1 but nothing seems to work. Here is my code

```
  override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/billboard.dae")!
        let billboardNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "billboard", recursively: true)

        //  billboardNode?.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 1)
        billboardNode?.position.z = 10
        billboardNode?.scale.z = 0.5
        //  billboardNode?.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.4,0.4, 0.4)

        sceneView.scene = scene
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified `billboardNode` is not `nil`?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial, they do something similar and that might help: https://mobile-ar.reality.news/how-to/arkit-101-get-started-building-augmented-reality-application-iphone-ipad-quickly-0177989/

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified `billboardNode` is not `nil`? You're sending an optional (the result of looking for a child node with a given name) position and scaling messages but if it's `nil` (because finding the child node failed) it won't have any impact.

The error suggests to me there was some problem converting the `.dae` file, which might explain why the scene can't locate the asset by name. Or it might be as simple as `"billboard"` vs. `"Billboard"`.